# Render a VBO larger than the screen,

Tags: opengl, lwjgl, tiles, vbo

So let's say that I have a large VBO that's larger than the screen that contains tiles, can I draw the whole VBO without losing any performance, or is there a method to only draw a sub part of the VBO that fill fill up the screen? Will the VBO take up a large part of the VRAM? The pros of VBO is the speed.

Comment: Are you sure you don't mean FBO?  VBOs don't have dimensions in the same way as the screen (the default framebuffer)  Technically FBOs don't have dimensions either, but FBO attachments do.

Comment: @bcrist you should read the whole question before commenting buddy! ;)

Comment: @Vallentin I did... what makes you think I didn't?

Comment: @bcrist because what he asks has nothing to do with FBOs and he doesn't mean FBO, he clearly means VBOs and the question makes perfectly sense.

Comment: @Vallentin No, the question doesn't make sense.  As mentioned in my comment and datenwolf's answer, a VBO can't be "larger than the screen".  You can't compare a scalar value in units of bytes to a 2-component vector in units of pixels.  Nor can the extents of the geometry contained within a VBO be compared with the screen, because vertices are, with few exceptions, always transformed using at least one matrix before rasterization.  Furthermore, "tiles" usually refers to texture atlasing.  VBOs have no connection to textures, but textures *can* be attached to FBOs.

Comment: @bcrist Yes It makes sense, and datenwolf also cleared out what the OP meant, as the OP said "VBO larger than the screen" he clearly meant if you render a VBO and only some of the content is visible due to translation, rotation, etc. what impacts does that have on performance and how would you only render a sub part of the VBO. That was what he meant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VBOs are just memory pools dedicated for holding vertex data. Nothing more, nothing less. It's prefectly possible to populate a single VBO with separate geometry data. It's even possible to have multiple data sets with different data layouts in a single VBO.

Only when you assign offsets into VBOs to vertex attrubutes using the `gl…Pointer` functions you add some meaning. The right `gl…Draw` calls will then make OpenGL take data of the VBOs and submit them for drawing.

It's nothing more and nothing less. So why am I telling you this? Because the notion of a *"VBO being bigger than the screen"* makes no sense. Portions of the geometry described by the data within a VBO may be outside the clipping region. OpenGL honestly doesn't care. It will just treat like all the other data. Only after the vertex transformation stage, if a primitive lies outside completely outside the clipping region, it will be omitted from rasterization. But it will pass through the whole vertex setup phase, hence consuming computation power.

> Will the VBO take up a large part of the VRAM?

A VBO **is** a part of the VRAM (dedicated for holding vertex data). That's the whole point of it. OpenGL buffer objects are memory pools reserved from the *fast memory* (and for all practical means *fast memory* equals VRAM). Period.